# Curve fit using lmfit, limiting result by sum of parameters

Tags: python, constraints, curve-fitting, lmfit

I have created a curve fitting algorithm that works, up to a point.
I have six parameters: a, b, c, d, e, f.
Each parameter can be between 0 and 100, but with the constraint (a+b+c+d+e+f) <= 100
Is there anyway to do this?

```
params.add('a', value=1, min=0, max = 100, vary=True)
params.add('b', value=1, min=0, max = 100, vary=True)
params.add('c', value=1, min=0, max = 100, vary=True)
params.add('d', value=1, min=0, max = 100, vary=True)
params.add('e', value=1, min=0, max = 100, vary=True)
params.add('f', value=1, min=0, max = 100, vary=True)
```

I did manage to find a, probably not very elegant, solution.
In the function I'm trying to solve I check if the the sum of a+b...+f is greater than 100. If it is I reset the coefficients with random numbers, forcing the algorithm to find another solution.

```
def myfunc(a, b, c, d, e, f):
    sum = a+b+c+d+e+f
    if sum>100:
        a = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10)
        b = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10)
        c = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10)
        d = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10)
        e = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10)
        f = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10)
Rest of function
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that `(a+b+c+d+e+f) <= 100` can be written as

`f = 100 - (a+b+c+d+e) - epsilon`

with `epsilon >= 0`.  Now, use that with epsilon as the variable and f derived from that:

```
params.add('a', value=1, min=0, max = 100, vary=True)
params.add('b', value=1, min=0, max = 100, vary=True)
params.add('c', value=1, min=0, max = 100, vary=True)
params.add('d', value=1, min=0, max = 100, vary=True)
params.add('e', value=1, min=0, max = 100, vary=True)
params.add('epsilon', value=1, min=0, vary=True)
params.add('f', expr='100-a-b-c-d-e-epsilon')
```

You still have 6 variables, but now `f` is not independent of `epsilon`.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work. However, it allows 'f' to be negative.

Comment: if you want `f` to be positive, use the `min=0` option as with the other parameters.